# Neo4J: how to find out the mode of procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, neo4j

Cypher query `CALL dbms.procedures;` allows to get *name*, *signature*, and *description* of all available stored procedures at Neo4J server.

Is there a Cypher query to find out the **mode** of procedure(s)?

*Source code of procedure should contain the annotation `@Procedure` with element `mode`. Value of the attribute `mode` indicates the type of actions ([READ (default mode), WRITE, SCHEMA, DBMS](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/3.1/javadocs/org/neo4j/procedure/Procedure.html#mode--)) that can perform this procedure.*

Answer (score 0):

Adding 'mode' here is a good idea, I'll add it to the issues list.

In the meantime, dmbs.procedures() does YIELD roles (in the enterprise edition), which you can use to reason to the associated mode, at least where the basic roles are used.

I think this logic should be sound:

```
call dbms.procedures() yield name, roles
with name, roles, 
 case when 'reader' in roles then 'READ' 
      when 'publisher' in roles then 'WRITE'
      when 'architect' in roles then 'SCHEMA'
      when 'admin' in roles then 'DBMS'
      end as mode
return name, roles, mode
order by mode asc
```

I'll look for solutions for the community edition.

Comment: Apparently, the `role` entity is missing in the Neo4j Community Edition.

Comment: Ah, forgot about that. I'll see if there are any workarounds here.